# How do I check user input against data in a table in php?

Tags: php, mysql

If the user inputs data in form field 'AddGuestName' i would like to query 'a_table' to see if they are allowed an additional guest. The column 'addguest' contains a "Y" if they can have an additional guest and a "N" if they cannot. If they cannot i would like to display and error message and not save the data until the 'AddGuestName' field is blank. Not sure where im going wrong.

**My Code**

```
$Name = check_name($_POST['name'],
 " Enter Your First and Last Name....Click Your Browsers Back Button To Re-Enter ");    

$RsvpNum = check_input($_POST['RsvpNum'], " Enter The 3 Digit RSVP Number Located On Your RSVP Card....Click Your Browsers Back Button To Re-Enter ");

$AddGuestName = check_rsvp($_POST['AddGuestName'], "You Are Not Allowed An Additional Guest.....Click your Browsers Back Button To Re-Enter");


function check_rsvp($data, $query, $result, $RsvpNum, $AddGuestName, $problem='')<br />
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   if ($problem && strlen($data) > 0)
    {
mysql_query($query="SELECT addguest FROM a_table WHERE rsvp_num=$RsvpNum");
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    }
    return $data;



    if (($result) == 'N')
        {
            die($problem);
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Be careful, you have a SQL injection vulnerability.. if the user passes in e.g. "1 or 1=1" for AddGuestName, all records will be returned. Note that stripslashes() will not help you here. Typically, you would use addslashes(), but since the input is not quoted in your query text, that won't help you either

Comment: You call check_rsvp() with two arguments, but the function expects 6 with only one marked with a default value. Does this code actually run?

Answer (score 0):

Are you meaning to `return $data` right after that first `if`? I'm thinking no...

Comment: should I? Because if no user input has been typed into 'AddGuestName' then it doesn't need to do anything, but if 'AddGuestName' string length greater than 0 then i want to run the mysql statment to see if they have that privilege indicated by a "Y" in the database

Comment: Putting that `return` right after the `if` will have it return every time. Now, put an `else` in there would do what I think you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT addguest FROM guests WHERE rsvp_num=$RsvpNum LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

if ($row[0] =='y'){
 ...
```